# How to find the interval between two dates (more nuanced than this, so greater explanation in the body)?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpmpe.png)[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFmx2.png)[image: Image of my sheet]

In this sheet, whenever you enter text into one of the update boxes, the corresponding date entry box gets populated with the date that it was entered on. I would like to find the interval between the dates (which then populates the final column with how many days are between the two dates), but there's three dates in this sheet.

People who use this sheet, might sometimes only need to use 2 update boxes, so I can't set the code to find the interval between "F" and "B", since column "E" might not be used at all. Conversely, I can't set the code to find the interval between columns "D" and "B" as some people might utilise all 3 update columns.

Is there any way I can incorporate column "G" into this issue e.g. if only the first two updates are filled, and the value in column "G'= completed, then the code calculates the interval between the dates that are inputted into column "D" and "B", and if all the update boxes are filled, the code calculates the interval between column "F" and "B"?

Comment: It would be useful to see some sample data and the expected output

Comment: `=MAX(B2,D2,F2)-MIN(B2,D2,F2)`

Comment: @JodyHighroller If I use that the field automatically gets populated with 0

Comment: @jdk8991 update your post to indicate what version of Excel you are using.

Comment: @JodyHighroller version 16.56

Comment: cybernetic.nomad added a new image. In the second row I would like the "`Duration of project" column to output the difference between "date log update 3" and "date log update 1". In the fourth row I would like 'Duration of project" to output the difference between "date log for update 2" and "date log for update 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use LET to store the duration.  If the duration is equal to 0 we will instead show a blank cell, else we will show the duration:

```
=LET(projDuration,MAX(B2,D2,F2)-MIN(B2,D2,F2),IF(projDuration=0,"",projDuration))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I also figured out that you can use an IF nested function to do this too